# Amazon Login with PHP CUrl

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I am trying to for amazon login using php curl but each time i am getting the error of cookies,the error says ,
 "Please Enable Cookies to  continue

To continue shopping at Amazon.com, please enable cookies in your Web browser.

Once you have enabled cookies in your browser, please click on the button below to return to the previous page."

i checked with StackOverflow previous solutions for the same but none of them helped me out. I cleared all the cookies even after that its giving same error.Help me out with this.

Thanks,
Priyanka

Comment: Look at the CURL Options, there is one to store the cookie

Comment: Which api you referred with  ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass cookies in the curl request itself. 
Add a key value field for cookie and pass the cookie value.

I don't think it will work every-time as most of websites use cookies to store authentication tokens.